# Next.js postcss font-variant overwriting

Tags: css, next.js, postcss

I am trying to set `font-variant: initial;` on some CSS selectors, but when it gets compiled, it is always overwritten with `font-variant: normal;`. This is the Next.js project with default settings, I haven't changed anything regarding the build process. When I run the `next dev` script it works well, but when I run `next build` followed by `next start` (as in production), it gets overridden.

From the Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config) I read that they do have some default `postcss` processing which includes `font-variant`:

Relevant part:

> Out of the box, with no configuration, Next.js compiles CSS with the following transformations:
> 3. New CSS features are automatically compiled for Internet Explorer 11 compatibility
>
> - `font-variant` Property

How can I turn it off so that the value stays the same after compiling?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the default PostCSS configuration by adding your own [`postcss.config.json`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#customizing-plugins) to the project with the `font-variant` transformation disabled.

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
        [
            "postcss-preset-env",
            {
                "autoprefixer": {
                    "flexbox": "no-2009"
                },
                "stage": 3,
                "features": {
                    "custom-properties": false,
                    "font-variant-property": false
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding `"font-variant-property": false`, but it is still compiled as `normal` even though I set it to `initial`. Btw, is there any documentation where I can see specifically what are these `features` and what are the options for each?

Comment: @djboris This is the list of features I got the value from: https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/blob/main/plugin-packs/postcss-preset-env/FEATURES.md.

Comment: Thanks again. I see that "font-variant" belongs to stage 4 (whatever that is), so I tried changing that as well. Still, no difference at all.

Comment: I still don't understand the syntax of the `postcss.config`, why are those settings nested, and why are some elements as arrays and some as objects? To me it looks like `features.font-variant-property` is belonging to `postcss-preset-env`, but then does the `postcss-preset-env` belong to `postcss-flexbugs-fixes` or is not related to it at all?

Comment: _"does the `postcss-preset-env` belong to `postcss-flexbugs-fixes` or is not related to it at all?"_ - it's not related. You can either have a string as the plugin entry (if you don't need to configure anything from it) or use the array syntax to customise the plugin's options.